# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NOT_FOUND, No address information found for supplied coordinates (latitude: xxx, longitude: xxx)., null, null)

Tags: flutter, geocoding

I get the same issue here:
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geocoding/issues/18

I tried to handle this exception with try and catch, but I failed!!

I know this error is occurred in the backend geocoding service, but how can I handle this error?